# How to make an image fill a flex item with flex-grow?

Tags: html, reactjs, css, flexbox

I've read through all existing solutions in which images could fill the containing divs but I haven't found a solution for filling a div without a static dimension, such as divs that only have been laid out by `flex-grow`.

Currently the image will destroy the `flex-grow` proportions I have set on the container. I want the `img` to just fill the div and not stretch the div out.

As much as possible I don't want to inline style.

Is there an existing polyfill or solution to this?

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
  flex: 1;
}

.sub-container {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.sub-container > div {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.first-container {
  background-color: blue;
}

.second-container {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.second-container>img {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  object-fit: scale-down;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sub-container">
    <div class="first-container">
      A
    </div>
    <div class="second-container">
      <img src="https://internationalbarcodes.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/QR%20code%20example.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jojonarte/tu3nbw4q/

Comment: Can you use the image as background-image in the css instead of using an img tag in the html?

Comment: Can you please clarify your question, because your code does exactly what it's supposed to do...

Comment: @rypskar the URL is just a placeholder what I'm planning is to provide the URL from somewhere else. i.e as a prop as I'm doing this in react.

Comment: You can set CSS properties from react, you can use some of the react magic or setting style directly on the element

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have this in your code:

```
.sub-container > div {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

Okay, that defines `flex-grow`.

But you haven't defined [`flex-basis`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis). As a result, `flex-basis` keeps its default value, which is: [`auto` (i.e., content-defined)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis#Specifications).

That's what you're seeing your layout: A flex item that is being sized by the content.

In other words, because the natural dimensions of the image are so large (in comparison to the size of the container), the image is taking up all free space and `flex-grow` is having no effect (it has no free space to distribute).

As a solution, add this to the rule:

```
.sub-container > div {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 0; /* new */
}
```

or, more efficiently:

```
.sub-container > div {
  flex: 1; /* fg:1, fs:1, fb:0 */
}
```

[revised fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hqtpr357/)

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
}

.sub-container {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

/* ADJUSTMENT HERE */
.sub-container > div {
  flex: 1;
}

.first-container {
  background-color: blue;
}

.second-container {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.second-container>img {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  object-fit: scale-down;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sub-container">
    <div class="first-container">A</div>
    <div class="second-container">
      <img src="https://internationalbarcodes.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/QR%20code%20example.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

More information:

- To avoid the problem described in the question, as a general rule, use the `flex` property instead of `flex-grow`, `flex-shrink` and `flex-basis` individually.

  *From the flexbox specification:*

  > [§ 7.2.1. Components of
  >   Flexibility](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-components)
  >
  > Authors are encouraged to control flexibility using the `flex`
  >   shorthand rather than with its longhand properties directly, as the
  >   shorthand correctly resets any unspecified components to accommodate
  >   [common uses](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-common).
- Learn more about [the difference between `flex-basis: auto` and `flex-basis: 0`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43529572/3597276)

Comment: I didn't know about flex-basis until now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use `background-image` instead use `img` tag and use `background-size: 100% 100%;`:

[See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jbku671m/)

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
  flex: 1;
}

.sub-container {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.sub-container>div {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.first-container {
  background-color: blue;
}

.second-container {
      background: url(https://internationalbarcodes.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/QR%20code%20example.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sub-container">
    <div class="first-container">
      A
    </div>
    <div class="second-container">

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't clear enough. I wanted to pass the image URL from somewhere else. I want the url to be dynamic.

Comment: here is how to change backround-image dynamiclly in react:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27966468/reactjs-change-background-image-dynamically